Next.js: how to check whether a component is rendered statically or dynamically?
Upon learning Next.js v14 course, I got to Chapter 10: Partial Prerendering (Optional) where it says:

Currently, if you call a dynamic function inside your route (e.g. noStore(), cookies(), etc), your entire route becomes dynamic.

Having done previous chapters in the course, I don't see <SideNav> component becomes dynamic after I use noStore() for other components in the route (which should make the entire http://localhost:3000/dashboard route dynamic according to the excerpt above. Note that I do not set experimental.ppr flag to true in my next.config.js).
My observation might be wrong, but is there a way to check whether a component is really using static or dynamic rendering?

did you try the npm run build. it will say which are static and which are dynamic

or to see it for yourself. throw in some console logs or render a Math.random(). static should give the console log in build time and render the same number everytime . dynamic should give different values and log each request

I did try npm run build. But it only confirms that the /dashboard route is dynamic without going into its components details: λ /dashboard (λ = (Dynamic)  server-rendered on demand using Node.js). Will try the Math.random() trick. Thanks!

let me know as well. i also followed this tutorial some time back

It's inconclusive (actually I'm confused even more :-D). I put something like <div>{Math.random()}</div> so that I could directly see how the value is reflected in the <SideNav> component. At first, the value kept changing -- I thought "Good, it's dynamically rendered as expected.". But then I commented out the components that use data fetching with noStore(), the value still kept changing

Are you running the dev version or the built version (npm run build and npm start)

My bad! Yes, I can confirm that this trick works now after npm run build and npm start instead of npm run dev. The value keeps changing in <SideNav> when it's used alongside with other components with noStore() (so the whole route indeed becomes dynamic, including the <SideNav>), and the value remains the same by commenting those other components out (the whole route becomes static).

cool. if you found the answer maybe you can post as an answer :D

There's still one thing that makes me shaky tho whether this is the proper way to do it: when I turn on the experimental PPR feature, the value keeps changing again while the  part is expected to be static.

havent really played with PPR so im not sure about that

Yah, it's alright. I guess I'm just gonna leave this question open -- 'cause who knows they might already have an on-going built-in devtools for this, other than our "homemade" experimentation/workaround. Thanks for all your pointers anyway :))

You can tell this at build time by examining the output of npm run build. Here is the relevant portion of an example output from the tutorial:
Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                    226 B          96.4 kB
├ ○ /_not-found                          870 B          85.3 kB
├ λ /dashboard                           298 B          89.7 kB
├ ○ /dashboard/customers                 142 B          84.6 kB
└ ○ /dashboard/invoices                  142 B          84.6 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all            84.5 kB
  ├ chunks/472-d678cdfa8ebba6a0.js       29.2 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-ad47410d9999f966.js  53.3 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-66b8f6b5c0574caf.js  219 B
  └ chunks/webpack-d5c332f5b3e20945.js   1.72 kB

○  (Static)   prerendered as static content
λ  (Dynamic)  server-rendered on demand using Node.js

Here, you can see that all routes except /dynamic are static.
AFAIK there is no similar mechanism for npm run dev (which I think doesn't have caching anyways?)
